# Read different lines from a text file and set different variables in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a text file with different lines like:

```
VMNAME-1="blah1"
VMANME-2="blah2"
VMIP-1=12.34.56.78
VMIP-2=98.76.54.32
PASS="something"
USER="else"
```

and I want to read this text file and use these values in a bash shell in lines like this:

```
create_vm.exp VMIP-1 USER PASS VMNAME-1
create_vm.exp VMIP-2 USER PASS VMNAME-2
```

any suggestion about how to do that?

Comment: `source text-file` then `$USER`, `$PASS`, etc. You'll need to rename some of your variables, though.

Comment: You mean in the bash just have source text-file at the beginning and then in the code create_vm.exp $VMIP-1 $USER $PASS $VMNAME-1 ? @bishop

Comment: This is what he means yes.... you can just use `source file.txt` in your script and you can use the vars in this file by referring to them as `$PASS` . Although some  variables like $USER in your file will cause problems because variable $USER is also defined and used by bash (restricted variable name) so you need to rename these values (i.e can be done with sed).

Comment: Yes, because the text file is in variable=value format, except for `VMIP-1` and so on. Those would have to change to `VMIP_1` for example (and sed can accomplish that).

Comment: PS: Don't forget to start your comments with @user in order user to be notified  for your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give it a run now.

Comment: May the force be with you

Comment: Sourcing the file does what you need, but perhaps consider using a tool that allows you to keep those variables and automatically apply them when you cd into some directory (it's a very useful thing to have): [direnv](https://direnv.net/) does just that

Comment: can I use source in expect files the same way I use it in bash shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the symbol names on the left side of the equal signs hadn't contained a `-`, then you could simply `source` the script, as all the lines would be valid Bash expressions.

However, that is not the case here, as `VMNAME-1` and others do contain a `-`, and so `VMNAME-1` is not a valid variable name in Bash.

If you know for certain that none of the values after the equal sign will contain `-`, then you could simply replace all occurrences of `-` with `_` to make the lines valid Bash expressions like this:

```
. <(tr -- - _ < input.txt)
```

And then you could write the create VM commands like this:

```
create_vm.exp "$VMIP_1" "$USER" "$PASS" "$VMNAME_1"
create_vm.exp "$VMIP_2" "$USER" "$PASS" "$VMNAME_2"
```

If the values may contain `-`, then you need to work a bit harder to replace `-` only at the left side of the equal sign. Here's a possible simple workaround that would work in some cases, but maybe not all:

```
. <(sed -e '/^V/s/-/_/' < input.txt)
```

This replaces `-` only on lines that start with `V`, and only the first occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Like earlier comments stated, You should
Simply use source /path/to/file And execute your script,
Since your text file's syntax is just like a variable initialization.

### Explanation

Sourcing actually runs the file you're trying to source in your current
Bash enviroment.
When you open a terminal and source the text file, you could use
The variables you've set, like $USER, $PASS, etc..
And you can do the same inside your script, to execute other scripts.

Comment: My variables list and their values (text file) is not in the same directory as my bash file. I have a trunk folder that my .sh file is there and the .txt file that is sourced in the .sh is in a folder in trunk folder. I just wrote at the beginning of the .sh file source \home\trunk\common\variables.txt . does it work this way? I didn't have to un it as my colleague is using the VM!