# How to set variables whose name and values are taken from a command's output with `declare` in bash?

Tags: bash, declare

I need to declare variables in a bash shell script for which both names and values are taken from another command's output.

For the sake of this question, I will use a temporary file `tmp`:

```
$ cat tmp
var1="hello world"
var2="1"
```

... and use it for my mock command below.

In the end, I need to have the variables `$var1` and `$var2` set with respectively `hello world` and `1`, with the variable names `var1` and `var2` taken directly from the input.

Here is what I got so far:

```
$ cat tmp|while read line; do declare $line; done
```

I know I don't need to use `cat`but this is to simulate the fact that the input is taken from the output of an other command and not in a file.

This doesn't work. I get:

```
bash: declare: `world"': not a valid identifier
```

and

```
$ echo $var1; echo $var2


$
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work since I can do this:

```
declare var1="hello world"
```

... with expected result. I assumed this would be equivalent, but I'm clearly wrong.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139630/read-different-lines-from-a-text-file-and-set-different-variables-in-bash-shell) as the closest thing to my problem, but not quite since it relies on a file to source. I would like to avoid that. I found other answers that uses `eval` but I'd prefer to avoid that as well.

Maybe there are subtleties in the use of quotes I don't understand.

If the only way is to use a temporary file and source it that is what I'll do, but I think there must be another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good suggestion when writing a shell script is that always double quoting the variable. Otherwise, it will be affected by the shell word splitting.

```
while read line; do
    declare "$line"
done < <(echo "var1=hello world")
```

And why `echo "var1=hello world" | while read line; do export "$line"; done` won't work? Because *`pipe` is a `sub-shell`, it creates `var1` in the sub-shell*, it won't impact the current shell. So it can't be *set in the current shell*.

As an alternative, use [`process substitution`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), you can obtain the output as a temporary file. So it will create the variable in the current shell.

Comment: This still won't solve the problem, if the OP executes a script ( running on sub-shell)

Comment: @zhenguoli I'm afraid this doesn't quite answer the question, since 1) it still relies on an external file, and 2) it doesn't work if there is an "=" sign in the value of a variable.

Comment: It works if there is an "=" sign in the value of a variable. And what do you mean that it still relies on an external file? @Jordan.

Comment: @zhenguoli, I was refering to the version with the command `cut`, which splits on the "=" sign.
Concerning the format, it is exactly the one of your sample file.
If I don't add the quotes on my output the line with sed is unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, that's my first version. I found that it is strange that `declare`  can evaluate a string with no error.  @Jordan.

Comment: @zhenguoli, the example takes as an input the file `tmp`. As stated I would like to avoid that. Moreover, if I don't use the `tmp` file but pipe the content to your command, it doesn't work anymore.
Example:

    `$ echo "var1=hello world" | while read line; do declare "$line"; done`
The variable `var1` is not set with `hello world`.

Comment: View my updated answers. Use [`process substitution`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). @Jordan.